# Sending an object to host from a client

Tags: object, inputstream, objectinputstream

I cant seem to find the problem on the code but it the server is not displaying anything. It displays the catch. Client seems find and it sets the players name and score and sends it but I cant seem to find the issue on this one why server is not displaying the name and score.

Here is my Client:

```
public class Client
{
  private static final int BUFSIZE = 64;
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {

    try
    {
                    int scores;
                    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
                    Socket clntSock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 6000);
                    System.out.println("What is the filename?");
                    String input = in.nextLine();
                    Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(new File(input));
                    ObjectOutputStream out = new 
                    ObjectOutputStream(clntSock.getOutputStream());

                    Player playerObject = new Player();

                    playerObject.setName(fileInput.nextLine());
                    System.out.println(""+playerObject.getName());

                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
                    {
                        scores = Integer.parseInt(fileInput.nextLine());
                        playerObject.setScore(scores);

                    System.out.println(""+playerObject.getScores().get(i));
                    }

                    out.writeObject(playerObject);




                    in.close();
                    fileInput.close();
                    out.close();
                    clntSock.close();

               }
               catch ( UnknownHostException ex )
               {
                 System.out.println( "Unknown host" );
               }

   }
 }
```

and my Host:

```
public class Host
{

 private static final int BUFSIZE = 64;
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
  // Step 1: Create a ServerSocket.
  ServerSocket servSock = new ServerSocket(6000);
  PrintStream fileOut = new PrintStream("Datafromclient.txt");

  try
    {
      // Step 2: Wait for a connection..
      Socket clntSock = servSock.accept();
      // Step 3: Get input and output streams.
      System.out.println("Step 3: Get object input stream.,");

      ObjectInputStream objectIn = new 
      ObjectInputStream(clntSock.getInputStream());

      Player playerObjct = (Player)objectIn.readObject();

      System.out.println("The name of Player: "+playerObjct.getName());

      for(int i=0; i <5; i++)
      {
        System.out.println("Scores:"+playerObjct.getScores().get(i));
      }  

      objectIn.close();
      clntSock.close();
      // Step 5: Close connection
      objectIn.close();
      clntSock.close();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
      catch (IOException e)
    {
       System.err.println(e);
    }

  }
}
```

My player class:

```
 public class Player

 private String name;
 private int playerId;
 private int bestScore;
 private static int numberOfPlayers = 0;
 private ArrayList<Integer> scores = new ArrayList<Integer>();

/* -------------- CONSTRUCTOR --------------------------------------
*/
public Player()
{

    numberOfPlayers++;
    playerId = numberOfPlayers;

}
public Player(String name)
{
    this.name = name;


}

//Create set method for setName
public void setName(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

//Create set method for setScores
public void setScore(int score)
{
    scores.add(score);
}

//Create get method for getPlayerId
public int getPlayerId()
{
    return this.playerId;
}

//Create get method for getName
public String getName()
{
    return this.name;
}

//Create get method for getScores
public ArrayList<Integer> getScores()
{
    return scores;
}

//Create get method for getBestScore
public int getBestScore()
{
    calculateBestScore();
    return bestScore;
}

//Method to expose the value of numberOfPlayers
public static int getNumberOfPlayers()
{
    return numberOfPlayers;
}

//Create get method for calcualteAverage
public double calculateAverage()
{
    Integer sum = 0;
    if(!scores.isEmpty())
    {
        for(Integer score : scores)
        {
            sum += score;
        }
        return sum.doubleValue() / scores.size();
    }
    return sum;

}
public void calculateBestScore()
{
    bestScore = Collections.max(scores);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was missing

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Player implements Serializable
```

now its working.